# Flex4 - Refreshing Auto-Generated Web Service Classses

Tags: web-services, apache-flex, soap, flex4, introspection

I am using Flex4 to connect to a SOAP web service. I'm generating the ActionScript classes using the Introspection Wizard in Flash Builder. That all works.

However, the web service is itself under development, so I need to periodically regenerate those AS classes to pick up the new methods or changed method signatures. The only way I've found to do that is to delete the existing classes, and re-run the wizard. HOWEVER, when I do that I also need to give the service a new name, or I see an error saying that the service already exists.

Is there any way to 'refresh' existing web service class definitions WITHOUT having to delete, come up with a new name, and re-create?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it -- Show View -> Data/Services. You can refresh the service there and choose which methods to generate code for...